# undefined while trying to calculate price in object

Tags: javascript

I'm taking the Codecademy Javascript course. I'm tasked with making a menu. I just learned about objects and I'm still a little fuzzy on the distinction between methods and properties right now. I've been following along to their video trying to debug my code but as far as I can tell it should function the same, if not be exactly the same.

```js
const menu = {

  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: [],
  },
  get appetizers() {
    return this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  get mains() {
    return this._courses.mains;
  },
  set mains(mains) {
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  get desserts() {
    return this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set desserts(desserts) {
    this._courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts,
    };
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
    this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  generateRandomMeal() {
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const mains = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const desserts = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price + desserts.price;
    return `Your meal is ${appetizers.name}, ${mains.name}, ${desserts.name}. The total price is ${totalPrice}.`;
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Caesar Salad', 9);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Octopus', 18);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Scallop and Lobster Stuffed Crepe', 22);

menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Berkshire Porkchop', 45);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Filet Mignon', 43);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Spicy Lobster Pasta', 47);

menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Deconstructed Mud Pie', 18);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Creme Brulee', 14);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cheesecake', 18);

const meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

The console is returning "ReferenceError: appetizers is not defined" at the 48th line when I'm calculating totalPrice.

As a secondary question, do the positions of the getter and setter functions matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 2 issues: you named a variable `appetizer` then tried to access `appetizers`, and your `getRandomDishFromCourse` doesn't return the selected dish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable name is `appetizer`

```
const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
```

but you using `appetizers`

```
appetizers.price
```

Comment: Although this is a correct answer, questions like this are not good for future reference, because it's a typo, and unless we want to have a seperate question for each possible typo (we don't), it won't be searchable. So in the future, instead of answering these questions, you should rather drop a comment pointing out the typo (to help the OP), then flag the question for closure as *caused by typos* (to help keep SO clean).

Comment: Sorry about that! I wasn't sure if I was overlooking something or if I messed up the idea of properties and methods somewhere in my object... I'll close the question if I can. This is my first foray into programming and didn't know where else I could find answers. Thank you :)

Comment: @ZachDavis I actually didn't target my comment to you... but to reply: everyone makes mistakes and that's not a problem, as long as one learns from it. :) As for finding/fixing typos in the future: you can use a smart editor/IDE that helps you catch them, and learn to understand error messages.